# How to share properties across multiple targets in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am a bit late in the game of "modern cmake" and trying to catch up. One question after reading target centric paradigm is how to share properties (include, compile options, definitions etc) across multiple targets?

More specifically, my project simply involves a few libraries and multiple executables as targets. They pretty much share the same includes, language features etc. Do I need to repeat it for *every* target? or just one target is enough for the rest? or any other alternative ways?  TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are dependencies between targets, then [`target_include_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) and other `target_` commands will take care of propagating the properties if you use the `PUBLIC` visibility:

```
add_library(foo ...)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC foo_includes)

add_executable(bar ...)
# foo_includes propagate to bar.
target_link_libraries(bar foo)
```

If there is no dependency relationship between the targets you can share option via CMake variables:

```
set(my_includes ...)

add_library(foo ...)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${my_includes})

add_library(bar ...)
target_include_directories(bar PUBLIC ${my_includes})
```